Why does my uninstall of a managed package fail with "<name> could not be removed during uninstall."?
I have a managed package that includes some "path assistant" components. When trying to uninstall the package I get the error:

<name> could not be removed during uninstall.
insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

The named metadata is a path assistant.
Why is this happening?

If the "path assistant" feature is not enabled on the org, you get this error. Turn the feature on and you can then re-try the uninstall, which should now succeed.
This is accessed through Setup > User Interface > Path Settings.
